# Is "is this video staged" scientific skepticism?

Tags: discussion

Re: [Was the "Worst Twerk Fail EVER - Girl Catches Fire!" video staged?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/17632/was-the-worst-twerk-fail-ever-girl-catches-fire-video-staged)

This seems like it will only be answered by journalism, not via scientific skepticism.

Or, can this be answered by scientific skepticism?

Comment: For the record, Sancho later found the information that revealed the answer to this question, but this question still stands about whether it is/was on-topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could be proven fake with a "Making Of" video or a confession from the perpetrators.

It could be proven real with the identity of the participants and a hospital report.

But most likely, it will sit unanswerable.

Comment: Are those methods of answer scientific skepticism? Or does it matter? Is our scope not actually limited to scientific skepticism?

Comment: @Sancho Verification of media claims has been on-topic since day zero.

Comment: @Sklivvz What is the media claim? The media have only described this video and said "some people claim it is staged".

Comment: @Sklivvz So, our scope is scientific skepticism *and* verification of media claims? Or is verification of media claims part of scientific skepticism?

Comment: @Sancho 1. the video clearly claims to be true ("I tried making a sexy twerk video for my boyfriend and things got a little too hot :)") so it is a claim, and youtube is a media; 2. Scientific skepticism is not a topic but the way we investigate claims. I am not quite sure why you are confusing the two.

Comment: @Sklivvz I'm not confusing the two. I doubted whether the route to an answer for this question would involve scientific skepticism.

Comment: @Sklivvz So we presume videos on youtube to be claiming they are not staged? And that is sufficient to support a question on this stackexchange about that video's veracity?

Comment: @Sancho, i did not say that, but a bunch of people do believe the video is true, so it's certainly on-topic here.

Comment: @Sklivvz You said "the video clearly claims to be true [...] so it is a claim". So that seemed to me to say that a video claiming to be true is good enough.

Comment: @Sklivvz So, if a video claims to be true, and a bunch of people believe that claim (I presume judging by the YouTube comments?), then questioning the video's veracity is on-topic here?

Comment: @Sancho Yes. Like Sklivvz said, scientific skepticism is a process by which we examine claims and that process can be applied to pretty much any claim.

Comment: @Sancho, just like finding a paper saying "the earth is round" is scientific skepticism, finding a report on Huffington post saying "this video was staged because ..." or, as in this case a video by the creator saying it's staged. Is the same process. the only thing different is the places where you look for your evidences.